# Where do gravitons reside - in atoms?

Tags: gravity, atoms

As a non-physicist, I imagine that if we have an atom of lead and an atom of copper floating near each other in deep space with no initial relative velocities, they will exert a gravitational pull on each other and accelerate towards each other.

Am I right? If so, where are the gravitons that cause this? Are there some in each atom? If I'm wrong, what is the true state of affairs as far as we know it?

---

P.S. If gravity is not a force, what is the supposed function of a graviton? Does it warp space around an atom?

Comment: Do words reside in people who can speak them?

Comment: I can totally relate to your feeling. I always wonder where are the waves coming from when I jump into a swimming pool. Are they hiding in me or in the pool before I jump in? Where do these waves (they are called MadMaxons in the Quantum Theory of Swimming Pools) reside?

Comment: @MadMax  - The difference of course is that we speak of, say protons, residing in an atom. I presumed that gravitons were particles.  Now, if you want to say that protons are waves and that they don't reside anywhere, that's a different story.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos - I would say that words reside in people whether or not they can speak them. There are certainly no words floating around entirely independent of people. In the same way a tree does not make a sound when it falls if there is no observer - a sound is not a wave, it is a sensation that occurs inside the human brain as a result of transforming vibrations in the air into information via sensors in the inner ear, integration within neural circuits, plus filtering and other brain activities.

Comment: There is no *conserved* number for gravitons, just as for photons and words. They *emanate* from anything and everything that has mass or energy, so, then also photons and gravitons. Their (gravitons') collective influence amounts to the fields taught in basic classical physics, as taught in basic quantum mechanics. If it helps you to dream of them shaping  ("warping") spacetime geometry, go ahead, but that is a useless, philosophical, connection.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos - I'm not dreaming of anything. I'm asking a question. With all due respect, you were the one who introduced philosophy by drawing an (unproductive in my opinion) analogy with words and people speaking them.

Comment: The warping question is meaningless. It has no tangible mathematical implications. Answers "yes", "no", or "yes & no"  are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos - I would be satisfied (partially) by being answered with "Yes", "No", or indeed "Yes and No" to the question "Am I right".  Please don't lecture me on logic - that is something that I do know about.

Comment: Gravitons, which are only hypothetical and unobservable in practice, may be thought, meaningfully, mathematically, to give rise to the gravity force. Spacetime geometry is an alternate, equivalent description of that force, and so gravitons may be connected to it, conceptually, but without producing any mathematical outputs beyond what you put in. Enjoy your logic.

Comment: Just to add one thing to this discussion... Often in physics, everyday words take on a very specific, technical meaning that may not line up with the everyday meaning. A classic example is *work* (force times distance) -- it takes no work (in a physics sense) to hold a 50 pound weight at a constant height over your head, even though it is hard work to do so in the everyday meaning of the word! Similarly, the word *particle* has a very special meaning in quantum mechanics. A particle is sort of a "small wavy-and-lumpy quantum thing," or in less whimsical terms a discrete packet of energy.

Comment: Massless particles, like photons & gravitons, *must* travel at *c*, so they can't exactly reside at some stationary location.

Comment: Many of the comments here seem to have missed that the questioner is not a physicist.

Answer (score 6):

> As a non-physicist, I imagine that if we have an atom of lead and an atom of copper floating near to each other in deep space with no initial relative velocities, they will exert a gravitational pull on each other and accelerate towards each other.

Yes this is right.

> Am I right? If so, where are the gravitons that cause this? Are there some in each atom? If I'm wrong, what is the true state of affairs as far as we know it?

There are lots of different ways of talking about any force, and in particular gravity, that *seem* mutually incompatible but are all capturing different aspects of the same underlying reality. I'll get to your question about gravitons, but I don't think what I'll say is particularly useful, so I'll give you some other ways to think about it first that I think may be more helpful.

- For weak gravitational fields (such as the one produced by an atom), we can simply think of gravity as a force as first described by Newton. The two atoms have mass, and so exert an (utterly, ridiculously small) attractive force on each other.
- In General Relativity -- which is not a quantum mechanical theory -- we can think of mass as curving spacetime, and what appears to us to be a gravitational force is really the motion of objects through a curved spacetime. It's also completely fine to use this picture, and say that the atoms produce an (utterly, ridiculously small) amount of spacetime curvature, and each atom moves in the curvature produced by the other atom (and itself).
- We don't have a full quantum theory of gravity. But we do have a *perturbative* description, which works when the gravitational fields are weak. In this case, the gravitational attraction can be described as an exchange of virtual gravitons between the atoms, in the same way that electromagnetic attraction between a proton and electron can be described by the exchange of virtual photons. Your question "where are the gravitions before the interaction" can also be asked of photons. The answer is that this is a misunderstanding of what is going on. You can think of graviton is a small fluctuation in a gravitational field that permeates all space and is always there (you can also think of a photon as a small fluctuation in an electromagnetic field that permeates all space and is always there). The graviton is created randomly by one atom, and destroyed randomly by the other atom *(**aside:** more precisely there is a probability amplitude for this process to occur and we need to sum the probability amplitudes for all possible processes)*. As an analogy, you can think of a violin string. If I pluck the string, I might hear the note C. Where was the C note before I plucked the string? I would say it's not there -- the string is always there, but the note is only present when I pluck the string, and eventually the note dissipates and disappears.

I just want to emphasize that even though the words I used in the above 3 descriptions are different, they all make practically indistinguishable predictions for the gravitational attraction of atoms. That's all physics can really do in the end -- make predictions about the outcomes of experiments. A popular hypothesis is that one day we will find a deeper explanation that supersedes all these different ways of talking about gravity, and which reduces to them in various limits. But, we don't know if this explanation exists, and we don't know with great confidence what it is.

---

In the comments, @CosmosZachos made a good point, which I summarize here. The number of photons, or gravitons, is not a conserved quantity. For example, an electron and positron can annihilate and produce two photons. This may be unlike your intuition of "ordinary matter", like in chemistry, where we expect the number of atoms of a given element to be conserved in a "typical" chemical reaction (not involving nuclear reactions). But there is no problem here -- energy, momentum, electric charge, and angular momentum are all conserved, and there is simply no requirement that the number of photons or gravitons is conserved.

Comment: It might further help the OP to emphasize that  there is no conservation principle for gravitons, unlike baryons ('protons residing in an atom') underlying the title of the question.   He seemed to miss the *reductio ad absurdum* of photons and words.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Good point, I've added a paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

In quantum physics, gravitational force is exerted by two massive particles emitting gravitons and receiving each other's gravitons. The gravitons exist only while in transit between the two masses, and travel at (or very close to) the speed of light.

The graviton is one of several force-carrying particles, collectively known as bosons. The others include the photon which carries the electromagnetic force, mesons which carry the weak nuclear force and gluons which carry the strong nuclear force.

But calling any of these objects a "particle" is misleading. Technically, a graviton is a wave-like excitation of the zero-point graviton field between the two massive objects and its propagation is governed by a wave equation. The wave "collapses" when the graviton is absorbed.

But in general relativity, the graviton represents a tiny, quantised curvature or kink in spacetime. A big pulse of gravitons can warp spacetime enough for us to detect the event by watching how it affects laser beams. Enough gravitons packed close together can comprise such a sharp curvature that spacetime collapses in on itself and creates a black hole.

Mathematically, the equations of general relativity describe spacetime curvature as a macroscopic geometry, while the equations of quantum field theory describe quantum field excitations as waves in some field which permeates that spacetime. The two kinds of equation have some tantalising similarities (especially for electromagnetic photons), but there are also major inconsistencies between the two approaches.

One problem is how a quantum gravity field can overlay a background spacetime when it is itself part of the fabric of relativistic spacetime.

Another problem hinges on the time-reversibility of the quantum equations. If you run them backwards in time they still make sense. But some events in relativity are irreversible, such as when a black hole forms. Black holes do eventually evaporate, but this is through a quantum mechanism (Hawking radiation) not a relativistic one.

Finding any unifying mathematical or conceptual framework has proved extremely elusive. A Nobel prize awaits whoever can come up with one!

Comment: Could you add a description of the aspect in which the two description cannot reconcile at the current state? I keep reading that, but it is not clear to me if they crash at some point and why they can't be alternative but valid descriptions.

Comment: @Alchimista Any better now?

Comment: @Alchimista I'd also add two points to Guy's very nice answer about what happens if you try and brute force glue QFT and GR together. (1) perturbative quantum gravity assumes a fixed background spacetime with gravitons as fluctuations on top of this. Similar things happen in QFT with other fields, but in gravity it's not clear what happens when there is *no background* (no spacetime!). (2) A basic postulate of quantum mechanics is that it is *unitary* (reversible). GR coupled to QFT in a naive way is not unitary when considering processes with energies large enough that black holes form.

Comment: @GuyInchbald yes. Note that my question is genuine. I would like to know if the problem is in the two predicting different outcomes, or if is that GR leads to singularities and must be abandoned while a quantum description isn't ready.

Comment: More added now.

Comment: Is it just me or does the whole idea of massive particles emitting gravitons and receiving each other's gravitons (that only exist while in transit between the two masses) seem a little put together like something Dr. Seuss would do. I mean where does it stop? A force carries a force carries a force etc??

Comment: @BillAlsept All the fundamental forces of nature work in this way. Gravitons probably have no mass, any more than photons have an electric charge. There is no recursion of the kind you suggest. Hope this helps.

Comment: @GuyInchbald I am not critiquing your answer but the overall consensus in general. The idea of gravitons is just silly when you think about it. First of all there’s nothing to back the idea at all. It’s like saying massive particles spiritually communicate with each other and create gravity. OK but how does that work? Overall it seems like a very weak theory. Even push gravity has way more credibility than that. No one can explain how gravitons physically do anything. Not to mention they can’t be found.

Comment: @BillAlsept If you would like to lodge your complaints with the creator of the Universe, please leave a message after the tone. More seriously... do you agree your complaint also applies to photons? If so, unfortunately I think you have to just live with the fact that the Universe is weird. If not, what in your mind is the fundamental difference between photons and gravitons such that you are ok with photons but not gravitons?

Comment: @Andrew photons are real particles that move from here to there And you can see their affect when they impacts s detection screen or knocked electrons loose in the photo electric effect. Gravitons on the other hand have never been detected and clean to do a lot more than just move from here to there. Gravitons are supposed to somehow magically reach out to another mass and somehow call the two to move together. No one explains how this is supposed to happen. They just say it. Like I said why do you need a force to carry a force to make something else happen etc. etc.

Comment: @BillAlsept I think maybe you haven't appreciated how weird photons are. You can equally say "Photons are supposed to magically reach out to another charge and somehow call the two charges to move together." And... yes, that's what happens. It's weird. No one really understands it. But it seems to be how it is.

Comment: The existence of gravitons is somewhat tentative because we don't have a satisfactory quantum gravity theory. But if gravitons *do* exist, we can be pretty confident that they're massless, or have an exceedingly tiny mass, thanks to the correlations in the EM & gravitational data from black hole mergers. However, gravitons carry energy, and all energy contributes to the [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) that is the source of spacetime curvature. So gravitons are a little different to photons, in that respect.

Comment: @BillAlsept Many people find many aspects of modern theoretical physics weird and incomprehensible to the point of unacceptable. But the maths works - reality really is that weird and incomprehensible. If you want to replace one apparently mad theory with another, it must of necessity be at least as mad. Theoretical physicists do not like this any more than you do. But they are still one step ahead of you; your maths has to be spot on or you are just fooling yourself and talking total garbage. Gravitons may prove not to be a useful model of reality, but not for the reasons you offer.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between photons and gravitons is in their probabilities to be emitted. Emmitting gravitons is highly improbable.

But if one speaks of the attraction force, it is always here, (Newton law $F\propto G\cdot m_1 m_2/r^2$). Nevertheless, in atomic problems this force is still too small, and it never is taken into account.